# What was the crime of the second condemned man in the second episode?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-handmaids-tale

Near the start of the second episode of The Handmaid's Tale, the bodies of two men are shown hanging by the "wall". As was astablished in the first episode, the drawing on the hoods that cover their heads tell of their "crime". One man has the star of david on the hood, probably meaning that his crime was being a Jew. The other person has a red X on the hood.

What crime does the red X signifies?

<sup>(In the first episode the signs for a priest, a doctor and a gay man are sown)</sup>

> [image]

Comment: I don't think they actually said what it was.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a number of things, we know it's a crime to attempt to leave the country or stand up to the ruling government, so those could be the reason for it. Alternatively it could be due to being a murderer, (going by the red and it being an X). It's never explored, nor is it a reference to an explanation in the book.